# Play - isMaxSizeExceeded() keeps returning false in test

Tags: java, playframework

I have several controllers in my play-based API with isMaxSizeExceeded to limit the size of request.
I set this limit via putting **parsers.text.maxLength=100K** to the *application.conf* in my project.

It works fine when I run my API in debug mode: when I send request with large form data, this method return true, and if I send small ones, the method return false.

But when I test this controller in unit test, no matter how large the request I send, this method returns false.

My controller is like:

```
@Security.Authenticated(AdminSecure.class)
public static Result MyAction()  {
    // some auth check
    // ...


    if (request().body().isMaxSizeExceeded()) {

        return ok("413: request too large");
    }


    // some saving and updating here
    // ...


    return ok("ok");
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
@Test
public void MyControllerTest() {


    FakeRequest fakeReq = getLoggedInFakeRequest(); // a method from my helper class
    Map<String, String> resourceForm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String jsonStr = "SOME REALLY HUGE STRING"; // this value is actually read from a file which contains the same text I used in debug test.
    resourceForm.put("resource", jsonStr);
    fakeReq.withFormUrlEncodedBody(resourceForm);


    Result result =
            Helpers.callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Resources.MyController(), fakeReq);


    assertThat(isResultContainErrorMessage(result, "413: request too large")); // isResultContainErrorMessage is a method from my helper class
}
```

I am using play 2.3.1 JAVA, by the way.

Is this an issue with Play or something wrong with how I tested the controller?

Thanks!

---

Here is the original question I put in Google Group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/fjbO2hNwXso